# Consolidating sheets in a workbook - Char limit

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the below code to add the data from different workbooks in a single sheet. One of my file names is 33 chars, it isn't being added to my consolidated sheet, as the char limit on sheet name is 30.

How do I modify the below code to accommodate the first sheet in the combined workbook?

```
Sub GetSheets()

Dim directory As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet, total As Integer
Dim WrdArray() As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

directory = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path & "\"

fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xlsx")

Do While fileName <> ""
    Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)
        WrdArray() = Split(fileName, ".")
        For Each sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets
        Workbooks(fileName).ActiveSheet.Name = WrdArray(0)
            total = Workbooks("Template.xls").Worksheets.Count
            Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(sheet.Name).Copy After:=Workbooks("Template.xls").Worksheets(total)

            GoTo exitFor:

        Next sheet

exitFor:
    Workbooks(fileName).Close
    fileName = Dir()
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I used this WrdArray() = Split(Mid(fileName, 1, 30), ".")

Comment: It worked for me. I'll modify the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just grab the first 30 characters when the string length is greater than 30 with this

```
If Len(Split(filename, ".")) > 30 Then
    WrdArray() = Left(filename, 30)
Else
    WrdArray() = Split(filename, ".")
End if
```

Comment: Not sure why you are using an array for this